# Get distance between two points on a curve in geometry nodes

Tags: selection-tools, geometry-nodes

Im trying to make a density thing in which I set a min value of distance between two instances and plug it in the selection of instance on points. Im working on a really simple ivy on which I want to instance some flowers, but a subdivided curve instances hundreds of flowers on the ivy. And i want to make a selection after a certian distance to instance the flower on the curve.

(a test project that I made to figure it out)
[image: Test project]

I was trying to do something with the capture attribute node and then getting the distance between points and try to manipulate it but it didnt work. Any help?

Comment: Could you perhaps clarify what your question is? Based on your description I'm not entirely sure which part you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can get a distance between start and end point, if there is only one spline in the object.

[image]

Comment: OMG Thanks! I actually forgot that Attribute Statistic node actually existed, you saved me, thanks :)

Comment: I would like to know the distance for every point and the next one on a curve. Is there already a field value that describes this?